# How to determine that I am at the "end" of a QIODevice?

Tags: c++, qt, qiodevice

I am attempting to come up with an algorithm to detect when the "end" of a [`QIODevice`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html) is reached (meaning no more data will ever be available for reading). Currently, my algorithm looks something like this:

- for sequential devices, wait for the [`readChannelFinished()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readChannelFinished) signal
- for regular files, continuously read data until [`atEnd()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#atEnd) returns `true`

However, the documentation for [`atEnd()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#atEnd) contains the following caveat:

> For some devices, atEnd() can return true even though there is more data to read. This special case only applies to devices that generate data in direct response to you calling read() (e.g., /dev or /proc files on Unix and OS X, or console input / stdin on all platforms).

This is where my algorithm breaks down. My next idea was to continuously check the value of [`bytesAvailable()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#bytesAvailable) when reading from a regular file. This yielded some very strange results for `/dev/zero`: [`bytesAvailable()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#bytesAvailable) returned `0` until I invoked [`read(amount)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#read-2), at which point it indicated that there were `16384 - amount` bytes remaining.

Is there any "proper" way to determine if there is still data available to read from a [`QIODevice`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html)?

Comment: I would argue that it is impossible to determine end-of-file for such special files that only generate content on being read from without actually trying to read from them.

Comment: Put Qt and C++ away for a moment. What do you expect (e.g. expressed in English language or expressed as an image) to be an "end" of `/dev/zero` or `/dev/random`?

Comment: @SimonWarta in that particular case, I don't _expect_ an end. My algorithm should always result in a conclusion that "there is more data available".

Comment: @NathanOsman Ok, what do you expect to be an "end" of a serial device? This is why QIODevice (and devices in general) don't provide and end-of-file signal, but provides (in certain cases an "hangup" signal when the other endpoint closes the communication (for example, a pipe).